# C++ LNK2019 unresolved external symbol stdlib

Tags: c++, std, unresolved-external

I have a program that requires atol() in one of its functions.  So I included stdlib.h but it doesn't seem to see it.

EDIT:  I'm aware to use it, I should include stdlib.h.  I did that but I'm still getting this error. 
The function:

```
void
intstr( char *t )
{
    long int atol( char * );
    long x;
    int i;
    x=atol(t);

    for(i=0;i<nilit;i++){
        if(x == ilit[i]){
        lsymb =symbol[nsymb++] = 250+i;
        return;}
    }
    if( 50 <= nilit){ 
        puts("** too many int literals**");
        exit(1);
    }
    ilit[nilit++] = x;
    lsymb = symbol[nsymb++] = 249 + nilit;
}
```

The error I get when I try to build

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl atol(char *)" (?atol@@YAJPAD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl intstr(char *)" (?intstr@@YAXPAD@Z)
C:x\X\X\X\Debug\p8program.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Don't declare system or standard functions yourself, use the proper header files. Read [this reference of `atol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) and pay close attention to the argument type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code:

> ```
> void
> intstr( char *t )
> {
>     long int atol( char * );
> ```

What's the point of this [`atol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) *wrong* declaration?
To use `atol()` in your code, just `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Note that the prototype of [atol()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) is:

> ```
> long atol( const char *str );
> ```

(The input parameter is a *const* pointer.)

Comment: I think the problem is that you declared by mistake a "new" non-standard atol overload, with a non-const char pointer, and the linker is trying to find its definition, and it's not finding it, since the correct standard implemented atol takes a const char*.